# Adding Pulses (Legumes) in Powder Form to Bread

Tags: bread, flavor

I would like to add powdered pulses (dried and ground) to the bread flour and experiment on the flavour of bread.

1. Does anyone have any experience with this?
2. Will fermenting the powdered pulse (with bread flour) have any bad effect (like toxin formation, bad taste, etc...)?
3. What pulses do you recommend to begin with?

I live in India. And I can only experiment with locally available pulses. But feel free to talk on any pulses!

Comment: As a bit of clarification, pulses are also known as legumes. From the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_%28legume%29) "Included in the pulses are: dry beans like pinto beans, kidney beans and navy beans; dry peas; lentils; and others."

Comment: @Jolenealaska thanks for clarification, I just edited the question to reflect that

Comment: Some beans require a good, strong boil for a while to break down phytohemagglutinin. An example is kidney beans. I doubt that'd happen when baking bread.

Answer (score 1):

Start with dried fava bean flour, or chickpea (garbanzo) flour.  Best to buy the pulse flour pre-ground, as it tends to be difficult to grind finely with home equipment.  Use initially only a small amount (<5% of total flour by weight) for flavoring, and gradually increase to taste.  Some other pulses can be bitter, and also be aware that any larger quantities can reduce the gluten content, which is less critical for flatbreads, but essential for risen loaves.

Comment: Chickpea flour has a rather nice nutty flavour - I've used it to make chapattis before.  If you have a recipe using a mixture of wheat flour and corn flour you could possibly try a straight swap of the corn flour for chickpea flour - neither has any gluten.